Автоматический перенос данных между серверами MSSQL
Доброго времени суток уважаемые форумчане! Ситуация следующая:
Имеется два сервера MSSQL, разные по предназначению но похожие по наполнению. У серверов имеются одинаковые базы A и B, с одинаковыми таблицами A.a и B.b. Постоянное изменение данных происходит на A.a, но нужно чтобы эти изменения автоматически переносились и на B.b. Вопрос - как это все можно реализовать?

Репликация SQL Server
